# Django: using C collation on a Postgres column?

Tags: django, postgresql, collation

I am using Django 1.7 and Postgres 9.4. I would like to create an index using C collation on a VARCHAR column in my database.

This is because C-collated indexes can apparently make `SELECT... LIKE` queries much faster, and I'm noticing that these queries are slow in my database, even though they are using a `varchar_pattern_ops` index.

From the Django models file, is it possible to specify that a particular index should use C collation? The [documentation doesn't mention this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#indexes-for-varchar-and-text-columns), so I assume not.

If I create the index manually in Postgres and specify C collation, can I then continue to use the Django ORM with `startswith` queries and use the index? In other words, will these queries from Django automatically specify C collation, or will they continue to ask for UTF-8 collation, thus bypassing the index?

Perhaps I could get round this by specifying that the whole database should use C collation, but I'm not sure. Any advice would be appreciated.